# How to get the active left and right margins to use them in a tikzpicture?

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to use the margins defined when [**geometry**](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) is loaded to draw several fancy section titles using [**tikz**](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf). In order to make `\Gm@lmargin` and `\Gm@rmargin` usable, I have to do

```
\makeatletter\Gm@lmargin
\makeatletter\Gm@rmargin
```

I'm only allowed to do so after `\begin{document}`. Since I'm defining many titles and other stuff before, I'd like to make those margins usable just after the geomtry package is loaded, or `\newgeometry` is defined.

Do you know how to do `\makeatletter\Gm@lmargin` before `\begin{document}` ?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
%I'd like to make them usable here
\usepackage{tikz,bm}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

%Definition of fancy stuff

\begin{document}

%I get errors if done before this point
\makeatletter\Gm@lmargin
\makeatletter\Gm@rmargin

\vspace{2cm}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
      \node[anchor=east,xshift=-\Gm@rmargin,rectangle,draw=black,fill=white] at (current page.east|-0,0) {Section};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

I've tried the procedures commented by [@Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967/heiko-oberdiek) and [@Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner), and this is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\newdimen\plmargin \setlength{\plmargin}{3.5cm}
\newdimen\prmargin \setlength{\prmargin}{1.5cm}

\usepackage[left=\plmargin, right=\prmargin, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz,bm}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning}

\newdimen\mylmargin \setlength{\mylmargin}{\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in\relax}
\newdimen\myrmargin \setlength{\myrmargin}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-\oddsidemargin-1in-\textwidth\relax}

\makeatletter
\newdimen\Gmrmargin \setlength{\Gmrmargin}{\dimexpr\Gm@rmargin}
\newdimen\Gmlmargin \setlength{\Gmlmargin}{\dimexpr\Gm@lmargin}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent
plmargin: \the\plmargin ~prmargin: \the\prmargin \\
oddsidemargin: \the\oddsidemargin ~evensidemargin: \the\evensidemargin \\
mylmargin: \the\mylmargin ~myrmagin: \the\myrmargin \\
Gmlmargin: \the\Gmlmargin ~Gmrmargin: \the\Gmrmargin

\end{document}
```

And the results:

```
plmargin: 99.58464pt      prmargin: 42.67912pt
oddsidemargin: 27.31465pt evensidemargin: 27.31465pt
mylmargin: 99.58464pt     myrmagin: 42.67912pt
Gmlmargin: 99.58464pt     Gmrmargin: 42.67912pt
```

Both work great. The solution provided by [@Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner) depends on the variables defined by geometry, as I asked. However, [@Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967/heiko-oberdiek) pointed out why it should be better to use the official length registers:

> \Gm@lmargin and \Gm@rmargin are not always defined. They are unknown if package geometry is not used. If package geometry is used, it depends on the options; for example, \usepackage[pass]{geometry} will not define them.

Comment: You're not using it correctly. Define in your preamble `\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Gmrmargin}{\dimexpr\Gm@rmargin}
\newcommand{\Gmlmargin}{\dimexpr\Gm@lmargin}
\makeatother` and then you can use `\Gmrmargin` or `\Gmlmargin` throughout your document...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What would you be using `\Gm@lmargin` for? The computations by `geometry` are in the `.log` file anyway.

Comment: @Werner, as you can see in the edited question, what you pointed worked, but I had to define `\newdimen` instead of using `newcommand`. I suppose the difference is that `\newcommand` would evaluate the margin every time it is called, and the `dimen` is only updated with `setlength`. Is it correct?

@egreg, thank you! I'm using it to define chapter, section and subsection titles with [**titlesec**](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) and [**tikz**](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf).

Comment: @U.Martinez-Corral: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @U.Martinez-Corral The sign for `1in` was wrong in my comment, just switch the sign.

Comment: @U.Martinez-Corral I would use a macro `\newcommand*{\myleftmargin}{\dimexpr...\relax}`. This way `\myleftmargin` is automatically updated, if some of the used values are changed.

Comment: @Heiko, great! I'll edit the question to correct it and tidy it up.

Thank you all for your very fast and accurate help ;)

Comment: @Heiko, if I use a macro `\newcommand*{\mylmargin}{\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in\relax}` instead of a `dimen`, and then use it inside the `tikzpicture`, I get the following error: _! You can't use `\dimexpr' in restricted horizontal mode.<argument> \dimexpr ...te] at (current page.east|-0,0) {Section};_

Comment: @U.Martinez-Corral How do you use `\mylmargin` inside `tikzpicture`? It works for the example in the first MWE as value for `xshift`.

Comment: @Heiko, I've edited the question to put the code at the end.

Comment: The example works fine for me after defining macro `\myrmargin`.

Comment: Apparently, it may be a problem with PGFmath, as explained in [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136017/using-macro-vs-length-to-set-tikz-coordinate-affects-placement-of-tikzpicture) question. I added `\the` to the macro definition, expanding the length to `pt`. It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\Gm@lmargin` and `\Gm@rmargin` are internal macros belonging to the implementation details that might change in any later version of package `geometry`.

Instead I would use two dimen registers instead of the internals:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\newdimen\myleftmargin
\newdimen\myrightmargin
\setlength{\myleftmargin}{3.5cm}
\setlength{\myrightmargin}{1.5cm}

\usepackage[
  left=\myleftmargin,
  right=\myrightmargin,
  top=2.5cm,
  bottom=2.5cm
]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz,bm}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

% Definition of fancy stuff
% \myleftmargin and \myrightmargin can be used here

\begin{document}

left margin: \the\myleftmargin, right margin: \the\myrightmargin

\vspace{2cm}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
      \node[anchor=east,xshift=-\myrightmargin,rectangle,draw=black,fill=white]
 at (current page.east|-0,0) {Section};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: @U.Martinez-Corral `\oddsidemargin` (`\evensidemargin`) still exists. The left margin would be `\dimexpr\oddsidemargin-1in\relax` and the right margin is `\dimexpr\paperwidth-\oddsidemargin+1in-\textwidth\relax` (if the "marginpar" area is not used).

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. I'm actually doing that as a workaround. But I think it would be more "elegant" to define the dimensions in a unique command (loading geometry or using \newgeometry} and have the variables updated automatically.

Since the macros may change, I've thought of using the \appto hook available with etoolbox. Something like:

`\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}`
`\newcommand\mygeometry{ %Code to update \myleftmargin and \myrightmargin
}`
`\appto\newgeometry{\mygeometry}`

Comment: @U.Martinez-Corral Then I would calculate the needed margins from the official length registers as shown in my previous comment. Of course, these calculateions can be hidden in a command, The full `\dimexpr...\relax` can be used as "read-only" length. `\Gm@lmargin` and `\Gm@rmargin` are not always defined. They are unknown if package `geometry` is not used. If package `geometry` is used, it depends on the options; for example, `\usepackage[pass]{geometry}` will not define them.

Comment: @U.Martinez-Corral Wrong sign in the first comment: reverse `-1in` by `+1in` and reverse `+1in` by `-1in`.