# Shifting the starting number of a ruler such that 0 aligns with the top-left corner of the body

Tags: expl3

In the code below, the rulers are positioned where I want them to be, that is 19pt to the left/above the body. But I would like 0, on each of the h and v rulers, to coincide with the top-left corner of the body. `\fgrulerstartnumh{-19pt}` seemed like the way to do it, but it only accepts positive integers. OTOH, if I use the []commented[-out] `\usepackage` instruction, I get the second requirement, but not the first. Is there a way out of this dilemma?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[type=none]{fgruler}
%\usepackage[type=upperleftT,unit=in]{fgruler}
\usepackage{xparse}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588521/shifting-the-starting-number-of-a-ruler-such-that-0-aligns-with-the-top-left-cor

\ExplSyntaxOn

\makeatletter
% Adapted from:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201488/how-to-get-the-active-left-and-right-margins-to-use-them-in-a-tikzpicture
\dim_new:N \erw_Gmlmargin_dim
\dim_set:Nn \erw_Gmlmargin_dim{\dimexpr\Gm@lmargin}
\dim_new:N \erw_Gmtmargin_dim
\dim_set:Nn \erw_Gmtmargin_dim{\dimexpr\Gm@tmargin}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\noindent
\verb|\erw_Gmlmargin_dim|~
\dim_use:N\erw_Gmlmargin_dim;~
\verb|\erw_Gmtmargin_dim|:~\dim_use:N\erw_Gmtmargin_dim.\par
%\dim_new:N \erw_hstart_dim
%\dim_set:Nn\erw_hstart_dim{\dim_eval:n{-1 * 19pt}} % ERROR 
\dim_zero_new:N \erw_hstart_dim
\dim_sub:Nn\erw_hstart_dim{19pt} % Workaround
\noindent{}\verb|\erw_hstart_dim|~\dim_use:N\erw_hstart_dim;~
\dim_zero_new:N \erw_vstart_dim
\dim_sub:Nn\erw_vstart_dim{19pt} 
\noindent{}\verb|\erw_vstart_dim|~\dim_use:N\erw_vstart_dim.\par

\dim_new:N \erw_hshift_dim
\dim_set:Nn \erw_hshift_dim{\erw_Gmlmargin_dim}
\dim_add:Nn \erw_hshift_dim{\erw_hstart_dim}
\noindent{}\verb|\erw_hshift_dim|~\dim_use:N\erw_hshift_dim;~
\dim_new:N \erw_vshift_dim
\dim_set:Nn \erw_vshift_dim{\erw_Gmtmargin_dim}
\dim_add:Nn \erw_vshift_dim{\erw_hstart_dim}
\noindent{}\verb|\erw_vshift_dim|~\dim_use:N\erw_vshift_dim;~

% \fgrulerstartnumh{\erw_hstart_dim}
% \fgrulerstartnum{〈num〉}
% The〈num〉is a nonnegative integer, which will be the starting number on the horizontal and verticalrulers. Default:\fgrulerstartnum{0}

\fgruler[in]{upperleft}
{\erw_hshift_dim}
{\erw_vshift_dim}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Insisting that you should use proper naming conventions seems pretty useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe that's right for you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[type=user,unit=in,showframe,color=red]{fgruler}
\fgrulerdefuserin{
    \rulerparamsfromfg
    \AtTextLowerLeft{%
        \rulernorotatenum
        \fgrulercaptionin{}
        \hspace{-5pt}\llap{\ruler[in]{downright}{\textheight}}}
    \AtTextUpperLeft{%
        \lower-5pt\hbox{\ruler[in]{rightdown}{\textwidth}}}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]